# Excel VBA: how to clear a selection without activating the sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Edit:

Not to clear the data in the selection, rather to remove the selection itself. I suppose this would be equivalent to selecting a different range, such as A1..

Comment: At least in Excel XP, there is no way to select a cell if the sheet is not active.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

erm, you can always use VBA to reference the worksheet and cell range?

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveValues()
  Worksheets("ACME_Sales").Range("A1:B17").ClearContents
End Sub
```

This will clear off cells A1 to B17 in the worksheet ACME_Sales.

**EDITED** Edit answer to reflect edited question.

```
Sub SelectNewCell()
  Worksheets("ACME_Sales").Select
  Range("E2:E2").Select
End Sub
```

This will let VBA remove any selection on ACME_Sales and then just select the cell E2.

Comment: edited question to clarify

Comment: @Nick - yeps you are right - you just select a different range to unset the current selection. Try ("A1:A1")?

Answer (score 0):

For a listrange you can all so make it like this

```
Sub test()

    ClearListRange sht, Range("PIVOTTABLEDATASOURCESSTART")

End Sub



Public Sub ClearListRange(sht as worksheet, Startrange As Range)

    sht.Range(Range(Startrange, Startrange.End(xlToRight)), Range(Startrange, Startrange.End(xlDown))).ClearContents


End Sub
```